# How to use XUnit with multiple sets of data while performing sub-tests?

Tags: c#, .net-6.0, xunit.net

I'm creating an integration test for our web API, payload and result are actually massive. Like it has at least 50 fields and returns an array of more than 200 items. These result items can be roughly divided into at least 60 sections. Each field can affect at least one of these sections, some can affect more than 5.

What's in my mind is to use InlineData to pass the path of the payload and check if it is successful. But how do I make the sub-tests for each "section"? I can't just lump everything in a single test, or perform multiple call just to test out each section, and it will definitely heavy if I have 60 tests that will call the web API, then multiply it by the number of payloads we have to test out several combinations of the fields.

Answer (score 1):

One approach you could consider is using parameterized tests to test the different sections of the result individually. You could split up your result into the different sections that you mentioned, and then create a parameterized test for each section. Each test would take the full result as input, but only check a specific section of the result.
You can test each section of the result individually without having to make multiple calls to the web API or create a separate test for each section. This should make it easier to manage and execute your tests, even with a large payload and result.

Comment: Thanks! But how can I do the chaining call of other tests? I only have a Theory test with InlineData to pass the list of the payloads. But from there, I'm stuck. Calling the sub-tests as you usually do won't display it in the Test explorer. Can you give me an example? Thanks!